# Extending an additional class within a main activity that already extends ActionBarActivity?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-actionbar

I am attempting to add the same action bar compatibility found in [the Google "ActionBarCompat" sample code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) to one of my projects.

My problem is that I already extend `MapActivity` in my main class, but the main class of ActionBarCompat seems to require that you extend `ActionBarActivity`.

Here's my Java 101 question: I know enough about Java to know that I can't have multiple inheritance, but not enough to know the  ideal way to handle this situation. My solution was to extend ActionBarActivity in my main class, but then make `ActionBarActivity` extend `MapActivity`. Is this the correct way to do this? If so, wouldn't I have to make a duplicate `ActionBarActivity` if I want it to extend other things?

Thanks for your consideration of this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a totally valid way of doing this. If you want an ActionBarActivity class that doesn't extend the MapActivity, you'll have to create another class. I don't think this will lead to a lot of code-duplication (which I'm guessing is what you're afraid of). Shame on the android developers though for making you need to code your own ActionBarHelper class.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example you provided - ActionBarActivity is only having an ActionBarHelper field and calling methods on it. Try doin the same in you MapActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Peter Knego"'s solution, and link to this library:

https://github.com/lvillani/android-compat-actionbar

or if your using Eclipse and svn :

https://svn.github.com/lvillani/android-compat-actionbar